# Problem when I try to open file and write into it

Tags: javascript, dom

Could somebody explain why the following simple script doesn't work in Firefox and how can I fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var w = window.open("a.php");
w.document.write("hello");
</script>
```

Thanks much

Comment: Could you exand on "Doesn't work"? what doesn't it do that you expect it to do?

Comment: @peSHIr. `open` and `write` in Javascript does not refer to file-io. Don't add those when the OP didn't - it only adds to the confusion here.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I'll refrain from editing stuff I basically know nothing about. Didn't actually read everything through: only answer there was talked about file-io.. :-/

Answer (score 2):

(edited to make the code sample display better)

DOM Scripting is more up to date and more robust.

e.g.

```
var w = window.open("a.php");
w.onload = function(){//you could also use dom ready rather than onload but that is a longer script that I've not included here
  var body = w.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("bar"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't read/ write files using javascript because it's a client side language? I may be completely wrong though!

EDIT:

Try this code:

```
var new_window, new_window_content = [];
new_window_content.push('<html><head><title>New Window</title></head>');
new_window_content.push('<body>New Window</body>');
new_window_content.push('</html>');
new_window = window.open("", "", "status,height=200,width=200");
new_window.document.write(new_window_content.join(''));
```

Cheers, Sean

Comment: Hey, don't you read what is asked here? Read the question carefully before answering.

Comment: sorry - the title should of been along the lines of "open a window and write content into it". The current title on a programming forum suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

To the others posting answers here: he is not trying to open a *file* and write to it - it is impossible in javascript in a browser. What he is instead trying to do with the `w.document.write` is to write to the end of the web page he has just opened in a browser.

Google Chrome says this code fails as:

```
>>> var w = window.open("http://www.google.co.uk");
undefined
>>> w.document.write("lol");
TypeError: Cannot call method 'write' of undefined
```

You first need to open the document stream by using `document.open()` - this will add a `write` function in `w.document`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var w = window.open("a.php");
w.document.open();
w.document.write("hello");
w.document.close();
</script>
```

Comment: I voted this down because the document.write() function is not what he should be using here. See Dawn's answer below for the better way, i.e. adding "hello" to a DOM element in the new page.